# LG Optimus 2X ICS Rom

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, rom-flashing, 4.1-jelly-bean, lg-optimus-2x

I came across a rom that i would like to try out on my LG Optimus 2X P990, but the xda page i found isn't for that phone. Any ideas on where i can download it?

the rom is called: [Rom] FB Jellybean Fusion Beta 3.2.2 [ICS | Fast][Jellybean Features & Theme]

Link to xda for the version not for my phone: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1828606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that developer released a version of that ROM that's compatible with your device so my advice to you would be to go to the Optimus 2X [forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1002) and find a Jelly Bean ROM there or you can check out this 
[link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) other roms: